# Get the window size on page load

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

Is it possible to get the window size on the page load?

Comment: You can link into whatever javascript event you want, but it will need to be with JavaScript Interop.

Comment: There is a package called BlazorSize that you might find useful

Comment: The proper way to do this is utilize the JS Interop to execute a`[JsInvokable]` attributed method for the update. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Hi Leo, have you resolved ?

Comment: HI @NicolaBiada, I found something similar that resolved my issue. I just posted it here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way of doing something similar that fixes my problem.

First, set this script function on index.html file:

```js
window.getWindowDimensions = function () {
    return {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    };
};
```

Then on your page where you want to read the screen width you need to read this function:

```
[Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
protected int WindowWidth { get; set; }
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var dimension = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<WindowDimension>("getWindowDimensions");
    WindowWidth = dimension.Width;
}
```

So every time the page reload we know the width of the window.

Comment: Not really an event though, is it?  What if the window resizes after OnInitialized ?

Comment: You need an event listener to fire every time when browser is resized. This solution is not complete.